Can a Visual Studio Test task in ADO have both .net framework and modern .Net (e.g .net 6.0) tests run in the same task
I'm trying to get MSTest unit tests updated from .Net 4.7.2 to .Net 6.0 for 2 large solutions and have picked on a single test project in each to convert first, leaving the remaining test projects in each solution to run as .Net 4.7.2. This seems to work locally, but the ADO Pipelines for each repo report that they can't discover ANY tests at all now.
All the test projects are sdkstyle projects with the same set of test packages:

Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK 17.10.0
MSTest.Adapter 3.0.4
MSTest.Framework 3.0.4

There is no runsettings file and the ADO pipeline task is configured to run as VSTest v2 using VS 2022 test platform, and to take any library starting with "Test" in the file name.
In ADO the output shows:
[MSTest][Discovery][path to Test.SomeProject.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly [path to    Test.SomeProject.dll]. Reason:Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Could not find or load a type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131522
And
No test is available in [path to Test.SomeProject.dll]. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Ending with:
##[error]Failed to negotiate protocol, waiting for response timed out after 90 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.
Any ideas on what might be happening here? Can .Net framework and .Net 6 tests exist together in the same ADO pipeline task?
Things i have tried have mostly involved changing the Test SDK and Test Adapter packages as these were solutions offered in other posts in stack overflow, Github, and elsewhere. Following these helped me get to the situation where tests pass locally and the failure is the same failure for both of the two solutions i am working with when tests are run in the ADO pipelines.
I have yet to find much answering the question of if tests can co-exist from both frameworks n the same pipeline task and/or how to solve errors like this in ADO when things are ok locally.
Expected outcome is that the tests run. If tests fail due to an error that has come about because of the platform change I can debug that, but not having the tests run at all is very frustrating when only changing one test project.

I shared a sample in my answer below. You can reference it and try to configure the pipeline of your project. @ChrisMartin

When different test projects with different target frameworks in the same solution, you can do like as below:

Install the NuGet packages used by each project. Due to the the projects have different target frameworks, you need to set that separately installing the packages that can be compatible and available for each project. You can do this by opening the solution in Visual Studio and then using "Manage NuGet Packages" feature to install packages for each project contained in the solution.

In Azure Pipelines, you can:

use one NuGet restore task to restore packages for all the projects at once.
Use one dotnet build task to build all the projects at once.
Use the VSTest task to run the .NET Framework 4.7.2 test project.
Use the dotnet test task run the .NET 6 test project.




Below is s sample as reference.

Projects within the same solution:

MathCalc/MathCalc.csproj: The main project that is a C# class library with .NET Framework 4.7.2.
TestMathCalc_Net472/TestMathCalc_Net472.csproj: Test project with .NET Framework 4.7.2.
TestMathCalc_NET6/TestMathCalc_NET6.csproj: Test project with .NET 6.



The pipeline (YAML).


# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildOutputPath: 'bin/$(buildConfiguration)'

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: MyLib.sln

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    projects: MyLib.sln
    arguments: '--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -p:Platform="$(buildPlatform)";OutputPath="$(buildOutputPath)"'

- task: VSTest@3
  displayName: 'Run test - TestMathCalc_Net472'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     TestMathCalc_Net472\bin\**\*test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run test - TestMathCalc_NET6'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'TestMathCalc_NET6/TestMathCalc_NET6.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build -c $(buildConfiguration) -p:Platform="$(buildPlatform)";OutputPath="$(buildOutputPath)"'




This is what we do. We have a .NET 4.8 web app and several .NET Standard 2.0 libraries. The web app test project must target .NET 4.8, so we use the Visual Studio Test task to run those tests. The other .NET Standard 2.0 libraries have .NET 8 test projects. While we use the Visual Studio Test task for those as well, we could use the dotnet test task for the .NET 8 test projects. Just need to reference different DLLs.

Thanks for this. It's helpful. I haven't had a lot of time to dive back in since this was posted.
Unfortunately we have a few C++ project in our solutions and it seems dotnet build is not able to build those (based on a github question & answer on an error message i saw about not being able to locate a c++related file).
I'm still having issue with 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0" not found for all test libraries in the VSTest task (that excludes the .net 6 test library).  In the dotnet test task I currently get a misleading error that suggests increasing a 90 second timeout.

@ChrisMartin, In pipelines of Azure DevOps, you can try to use the MSBuild or VSBuild task to build the C++ projects.
